# SQL Inner join statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, xaml

I'm working on a school project

I want to get all the information of the bands, which works fine. Until i get to genres.
Genre is a bit special, because a band can have multiple genres and vice versa.

So in SQL I have a table Bands, a table Genre and a table Band_Genre
If i do the inner join there

```
SELECT * 
FROM Band 
INNER JOIN Band_Genre 
        ON Band.ID = Band_Genre.BandID
```

Everything works fine in SQL but when i try a second reader with that statement it returns null.

But what i want to do now is fill the datagrid with the genres themselves, not the ID's.
So what i think is that i need to get the ID out of the Inner join and link it to Genre.Name

Maybe this goes a bit far but
I would be happy if someone could already get the id's into the ObservableCollection.
So that the Datagrid shows Genres: 1, 3 for example.

Thanks in advance

```
C#
//Property
private ObservableCollection<Genre> genres;

        public ObservableCollection<Genre> Genres
        {
            get { return genres; }
            set { genres = value; }
        }
//Method
public static ObservableCollection<Band> GetBands()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Band> list = new ObservableCollection<Band>();
            try
            {
                string provider = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ProviderName;
                string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                DbConnection con = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider).CreateConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
                con.Open();

                DbCommand command = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider).CreateCommand();
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.Connection = con;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Band";

                //Bands ophalen
                DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Band b = new Band()
                    {                       
                        ID = reader["ID"].ToString(),
                        Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                        Picture = reader["Picture"].ToString(),
                        Description = reader["Description"].ToString(),
                        Twitter = reader["Twitter"].ToString(),
                        Facebook = reader["Facebook"].ToString(),
                        //Genres = (Genre)reader["Genres"] lijst van genres kunnen doorgeven, probleem met meerdere genres per band. Kijken filmpje inner joint
                    };

                    if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["Picture"]))
                    {
                        b.Picture = reader["Picture"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        b.Picture = null;
                    }
                    list.Add(b);
                }

                //Genres ophalen via INNER JOIN
                DbCommand command2 = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider).CreateCommand();
                command2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command2.Connection = con;
                command2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Band INNER JOIN Band_Genre On Band.ID = Band_Genre.BandID";

                 //Bands ophalen
                DbDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    Genre g = new Genre()
                    {
                       ID = reader2["GenreID"].ToString(),
                       //Name = reader2[


                    };
                }

                reader.Close();
                reader2.Close();
                con.Close();
            }

XAML:
<DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Band"  Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Picture" Binding="{Binding Picture}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Twitter" Binding="{Binding Twitter}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Facebook" Binding="{Binding Facebook}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Genres" Binding="{Binding Genres}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: ID = reader2["GenreID"].ToString(), use semicolon And a semicolon after } remove it

Comment: That's not the problem, when I Place a breakpoint on DbDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader(); I get a null. So the error happends before that.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to do... The second reader should not be returning null unless your tables don't have the correct data in - but it won't have the genre info. For genres you want to inner join to Genre, don't you?

```
SELECT g.*
FROM Band b
INNER JOIN Band_Genre bg
    ON b.ID = bg.BandID
INNER JOIN Genre g on g.GenreID = bg.GenreID
```

This will return your Genre info. But if your second reader is null it looks like Band_Genre is not populated or has incorrect ID's so it can't join to your Band table

**EDIT**

If you want them all in one query:

```
SELECT b.*, g.*
FROM Band b
INNER JOIN Band_Genre bg
    ON b.ID = bg.BandID
INNER JOIN Genre g on g.GenreID = bg.GenreID
```

Comment: What i think is strange is that the band and genres belong together but i do need a second reader for them. So i want the band name,description,etc... but that already works. Only the Genre part stays empty

Comment: Nope, it keeps returning me null