# My datareader (c#) seems can't store my data when I use an Inner Join request

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

At first, I wish to make clear that my problem have been encountered one time in 2013, but there is no answers which solve my problem (topic sql-inner-join-statement-in-c-sharp).

The goal of my project is to retrieve datas for a SQL Server database, in a C# program, and thereafter convert them in json.

What I want right here, is to execute a request of this nature:

```
SELECT 
    *data_from_table1*, *datas_from_table2* 
FROM
    Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table2 ON *Link_between_tables*;
```

I have tried my request in SQL Server, and I retrieve the data I want, so the request is good.

In my C# program, I use a `SqlDataReader` to execute this SQL statement, and store my data I retrieve in a dynamic list of strings like that:

```
list<list<string>>
```

Then, to test it, I display this list.

But in my list, there is only my data from my first table. Data from the second one (the linked one) are all `NULL`.

(I tried with an arraylist then, same results ...)

I put my code on pastbin: https://pastebin.com/xS3aByWu `pastebin link`

At first, I want to know if it's possible at least to do an inner join request with `SqlDataReader`, and if possible to know how make it work.

Hope someone can help me. Have a good day

Comment: [Request sql-server screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/UK2vE)

Comment: [Result_display_list_screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/3X9bo)

Comment: [Topic with the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141214/sql-inner-join-statement-in-c-sharp)

Comment: include all necessary information in the question. The comments are comments...

Comment: I have under 10 pts of reputation, so i can link only one time in my question ..

Comment: We need to see the actual code for "and store my data I retrieve in a dynamic list of strings like that:", my gut tells me that is where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I find my problems. I used:

```
INNER JOIN
```

instead of:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
```

There is probably a problem with *LEFT* or *RIGHT* Joins. I don't know which one, but apparently, it exist.

I would have prefer a *LEFT JOIN* for my project, but i'll try to work with it

I close the subject.